# What is a viable strategy to reach a particular cache hit ratio?

Tags: caching, memcached, ehcache

Our team is working on building a cache layer for a key-val lookup service, which have general guideline to use 2 level cache: in-host and distributed layer. There is a requirement of 70% cache hit ratio, so only 30% of traffic is expected to fall into the downstream NoSQL. At the begining, we can figure out some factors that influence to the hit ratio:

1. TTL
2. Cache size
3. The query pattern: e.g. 15% of the keys are usually queried than other.
4. ... other?

We also have some initial ideas on achieve it, like do some prefetching data to cache, e.g 70% data. But at the end of the day I realize that it's more complicated than we think and we need a stronger rationale.

Do we have any resource/research or paper related to the issue? Or what is the proper approach to do some test or spike it?

Comment: If you capture a request trace, you could quickly [simulate](https://github.com/ben-manes/caffeine/wiki/Simulator) different sizes and policies. Understanding the workload's characteristics (freq vs recency) is probably a good first step.

Comment: Thanks Ben, simulation seems to be a good starting point.

Answer (score 1):

There are 3 main factors that influence your hit ratio:

1. Access pattern
2. Caching strategy
3. Working set size to cache size relation

The access pattern is generally out of your control because it depends on how users access your service. You do have control over the caching strategy but it is generally not straight forward how to change it to improve your hit ratio. The working set is generally not in your control because it depends on the access pattern but you do have control over your cache size.

I would approach your situation as follows:

1. Make sure the working set fits into your cache (easy to do)
2. Improve the cache strategy (more complex and time consuming)

To find out your working set size and make sure it fits in the cache you can start with a small cache and gradually (every couple of days for example) increase the cache size and see how much the hit ratio increases. The hit rate increase will become smaller and smaller the bigger the cache gets and once you hit the point of diminishing returns you know your working set size. The hit rate you get at this point is the maximum you will get for your caching strategy.

If your working set fits into your cache and you hit your 70% requirement, you are done. If not, you will need to tweak your caching strategy. This is basically requires clever engineering. Simulation like Ben Manes suggests is definitely a very useful tool for such clever engineering.